# How to fix version mismatch between Angular CLI and Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update my angular in my app to version `13.2.3`. I noticed that after following the official update guide I ended up with a global version of Angular `14.0.0-next.2`. You can see the version mismatch between CLI and core components in the output of `ng v` below.

How could I fix this? I'd like to use version `13.2.3` everywhere. I tried reinstalling the CLI but it made no difference.

```
Node.js version v17.2.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 13.2.3
Node: 17.2.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.4
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 14.0.0-next.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1302.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      13.2.3
@angular-devkit/core               13.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         13.2.3
@angular/cdk                       13.2.2
@angular/cli                       13.2.3
@angular/flex-layout               8.0.0-beta.26
@angular/material                  13.2.2
@angular/material-moment-adapter   13.2.2
@schematics/angular                13.2.3
rxjs                               7.5.4
typescript                         4.5.5
```

Comment: You can simply make the changes manually in your package.json file.

Comment: @WillAlexander that's what I did, I have no references to `v14` in `package.json`. I made the changes and ran `npm install` but the version did not change.

Comment: To the person that voted to close my issue because there are not enough details? Could you comment what details are needed? I'm happy to add them

Comment: Your global Angular version has no effect on the version you are using in a specific project. If you want to install a specific version globally, use `npm i -g @angular/cli@13.2.3`